# Can't build offline with Appodeal SDK in Android Studio 3.6.1

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, appodeal

I integrated Appodeal SDK in my project. Now I can't run the offline build in Android Studio. It says

```
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:[15.0.0,17.0.0).
```

Which are needed by some internal network adapters of the Appodeal. So, I am stuck with the online build each time. I tried clear cache and restart. Even did `gradlew build --refresh-dependencies` which took a long time to finish.